# Why is websocket which is receoving periodic data causes rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, react-hooks

Just by instantiating the following code in another components

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import useWebSocket, { ReadyState } from 'react-use-websocket';

export const WebsocketHandler = () => {
    const { lastJsonMessage, readyState } = useWebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8001/ws', { 
        shouldReconnect: (closeEvent) => {
        return true;
      }, 
      reconnectAttempts: 99999,
      reconnectInterval: 5000 
    });

  const [isResponsive, setIsResponive] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("lastJsonMessage: " + JSON.stringify(lastJsonMessage));
    }, [lastJsonMessage])

    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("readyState: " + readyState);
    }, [readyState])

  return isResponsive;
};
```

I got rerenders or to be more precise, i got some console output from my other components, so it looks like stuff is rerendered on every receive. I don't use the return value, so whats going on here? How can I avoid that?
Edit: The console log in this compoment is not the issue. The output will also come from other compoments in the application.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` will run everytime `lastJsonMessage` or `readyState` value change. `useEffect` is a react hook and will run after side effects based parameters. For more info [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

> Data fetching, setting up a subscription, and manually changing the
> DOM in React components are all examples of side effects. Whether or
> not you’re used to calling these operations “side effects” (or just
> “effects”), you’ve likely performed them in your components before.

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think
> of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and
> componentWillUnmount combined.

If you don't want to logging delete the both useEffects. if you want console log once

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("lastJsonMessage: " + JSON.stringify(lastJsonMessage));
    console.log("readyState: " + readyState);
}, [])
```

but this code may want to change based your want

Comment: Sorry to be not clear enough here, I got the output from other components, it looks like that receiving information via the websocket will cause global refresh. The used effects here to output the received data is clear to me and not the issue.

Comment: @boiler oh I think You are creating new websocket for every component. So You can solve this with creating one global websocket and import it to all components and use same websocket and handler

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I still have one websocket for the whole application in a context. It looks like that my own heartbeat message in conjunction with lastJsonMessage will cause these rerenders....still looking.

Comment: Do you call your websocket with useEffect in your component? Because it will run continuously everytime your data change and it will cause rerender. Can you add component code to your question(only websocket initialize and run block)

Comment: I observe lastJsonMessage in these objects to get status of heartbeat from websocket...it looks like the trick is to filter out heartbeat if it doesn't change...or in other words only evaluate differences.